# Catalyst: global init action

Tags: perl, catalyst

In Catalyst framework there is a global `init` sub(executed before any controller). i want the set some `config` variable from DB(like supper admin `id` or admin email for GPG configuration ).

i tried to use `auto` and 'begin' actions but those actions are just executed for its corresponding controller.

in `Root.pm` file:

```
sub auto :Private {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    my $config = $c->model('DB')->resultset('Config')->single();
    $c->config->{var1} = $config->var1;

};
```

When i request another controller like `Controller2` and `begin` , the `$c->config->{var1}` was empty..

Comment: There does not appear to be a question here.

Comment: I think it's "How do I set a config variable from DB?", but that's pretty vague. It would help to know a bit more precisely what problem was encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of configuration belongs in the main program, i.e. `MyApp.pm`, so it is set before you even think about accepting a request. You don't normally want to be configuring database connectivity during every request cycle.

Your question isn't entirely clear, but if you *do* need to configure database settings on every request, then the `auto` sub in the root controller `Root.pm` would be the place to ensure it happened at the top of every request.

But I can't help feeling there's an X-Y problem in here...

Comment: Some informations like GPG homedir, email admin and Supper admin Id... should be configurable. @RET i already tested the `auto` sub in `Root.pm` controller, but this sub execute only for this controller.

Comment: @Abir I think that you don't really have a full understanding on `auto` and it's role in the request chain. So before you do any more poking around in here, look back at the comments on your question, and please re-write your question as, "What you are trying to achieve", "how you have tried it", and "what has failed for you". You'll get more help that way.

Comment: the prob is that `begin` sub is executed before `auto` sub. so when i check the value of `$c->config->{var1}` in `controller2` in `begin` sub it was empty :p